# Maintaining a Linked List in File

Tags: c++, file, serialization, linked-list

As a part of the programming Assignment, I have to maintain a linked list in text file. I am pretty convenient with Linked List datastructure, but not so much with files in C++. Can some one give me an idea or overview of how to approach it. I should be able to add or delete the linked list, also able to add or delete the nodes in the linked list or else and should reuse the space that was deleted on one linked list. Each list has a number(integer), all nodes are of same size, contain integer.

My idea would be,

1) maintain a file with numbers(that contain linked List numbers)

```
0 - NULL
1 - head_offset for_linked_list_num 1
0 - NULL 
1 - head_offset_for_linked_list_num 3
1 - head_offset_for_linked_list_num 3
1 - head_offset_for_linked_list_num 3
```

etc
where -1 is the termiator indication, 1 in a position indicates the ith location has an location associated with it

2) open another file and maintain the linked list like this

```
data next_offset
data next_offset
data NULL
```

By doing this, I can keep track of the linked list and efficiently add/delete/display an array.

For doing in C++ what are the functions I need to know and learn. I have very less time and I can code thinking it as an basic level of functions. Please advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you having to maintain one link list or multiple lists?

Comment: multiple lists, but I guess the nodes can interchange between them. Btw, how much would you rate the assignment out of 10. Despite programming in C++ for over 2 years, I feel it as kind of difficult.

Comment: Maybe a really stupid question, but why don't you just store one element per line? Delete an element, delete the line. Insert an element, insert a line.

Comment: That would cause fragmentation, I guess. Also, I need to reuse the list again. I need a way to store a offset and offset should not change, no matter what, because If I disturb the offset then my entire file will change.

Comment: Don't worry about maintaining offsets -- rewriting the entire file when the underlying lists change is perfectly fine, especially for a first implementation.

Comment: Or else is there a way to reserve a line with this particular size? so the offset never changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 solution could be to have each list it's own file. The number would be the file name on disk.  Inside of the file the first line is always the head node. Each line would be two peices of data. The node data followed by the line in the file for the next node. This would allow you to reuse empty spaces that have been deleted. (a -1 for the next node line would be the end of the list. For example:

1.txt:

```
(data) (next node lines number)
18     2
32     4
4      -1
5      3
```

So this link list would be 18 -> 32 -> 5 -> 4

Comment: I guess this is the design I am going to go with for right now. Will let you know. Thanks. Btw, Can You give me an example of how to traverse to a particular line???

Comment: I guess that would take lots of iterations.

Comment: If you want to reduce the iterations and not read the entire file into memory in one go, you should probably look into reading/writing the file in a binary format so that you can seekg into places into the file.  Then the last value would be the seek position of the next element rather than line number.  Plus since the data is all of uniform size (Integer) you know how many bytes each takes, which just screams binary file format.  IMO

Comment: sounds like an cool idea. SO what I will do is to write the file in binary mode, so the offset wont change and then in Binary mode, I can still delete a node and then use the space again. Let me know, if I am correct.

Comment: Take a loot at this article (I know I hate the fact that it is split up into multiple pages too) on random access with binary files in c++: http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/random_4.htm  It will give you some more knowledge that might help you better design your structure.

Answer (score 0):

For the what functions to use question, you might consult:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-on-Streams.html#I_002fO-on-Streams
A read through this section may take 15 minutes and covers the basics.